# SDL - Segmentation Fault (core dumped), any thoughts?

Tags: c, ubuntu

Having this problem since I've installed SDL. First of all, I've tried to install it with the tar.gz file, didn't went ok when trying to compile (terminal couldn't find the dir for SDL lib), so after that I've installed the synpatic pack mng, and sucessfully downloaded the "libsdl1.2-dev" file. 
I am following lazzy foo's tutorial for SDL, whenever I try to compile a simple code to create a screen and blit an image, i get the following message in the terminal:

(gcc -Wall -o teste teste.c -lSDL -lSDL_image)

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Here it is my code in C:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "SDL/SDL.h" 

    int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
    {
    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    if (screen == NULL) {
        printf("SDL_SetVideoMode failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1); /* Unrecoverable error */
    }

    hello = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");

    SDL_BlitSurface(hello, NULL, screen, NULL);

    SDL_Flip(screen);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    SDL_FreeSurface(hello);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
    }
```

- I've already made sure that hello.bmp is in the same dir of my teste.c file.

Here's a log using gdb to backtrace:

LOG

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.8-1ubuntu4) 7.8.0.20141001-cvs
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from teste...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/lazzo/Documentos/Treino/teste 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff707c700 (LWP 5605)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
SDL_Flip (screen=0x0) at ./src/video/SDL_video.c:1109
1109    ./src/video/SDL_video.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  SDL_Flip (screen=0x0) at ./src/video/SDL_video.c:1109
#1  0x00000000004009a2 in main ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 0x7ffff7fd8740 (LWP 5601) exited]

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) q
]0;lazzo@J-Ubuntu: ~/Documentos/Treinolazzo@J-Ubuntu:~/Documentos/Treino$ exit
exit
```

END OF LOG

Any help you guys could give me would be really appreciated, and I apologize for my bad english, I am from Brazil and still learning english.

UPDATE

After adding Klas suggestion to my code, I've got this from terminal:

"SDL_SetVideoMode failed: No avaible video device"

How is that even possible? (my videocard is a radeon HD 4850 btw)

Comment: Syntax :
$ gcc [options] [source files] [object files] -o output file

Comment: Output filename should immediatly follow `-o` option.

Comment: The call to `SDL_SetVideoMode` returned `null`. If you get a return value of `null` you should call `SDL_GetError` immediately after to check what the error is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind pointing out how exactly I should do that? Please? I am really newbie when it comes to SDL, in case that wasn't clear already. :/

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Lol, wtf, setting it the way you pointed to returned to me:

SDL_SetVideoMode failed: No avaible video device

how is that even possible?

Comment: My videocard is a Radeon HD 4850 btw

Comment: Maybe try `SDL_ListModes()` or maybe `SDL_GetVideoInfo()` for debugging this problem, and check what they return (do this before trying to call `SDL_SetVideoMode()`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jubatian. Using your instructions I've compiled the following example that I've found here:

http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdllistmodes.html


Unfortunately that example led me to another "Segmentation Fault(core dumped)" error message.

Comment: Give it some `printf` debugging. A `printf` before and after every SDL call never hurts, and you will know where things bail away (and if you are there, you may also use the `printf`'s to output some info which may help you locating why that happens). If the `printf`'s would reveal that `SDL_ListModes()` itself crashes, maybe check `SDL_GetVideoInfo()` as well (it is documented to use that if the first parameter is `NULL` as in the example). Something fishy might be going on here.

Comment: According to the printf's positioned before and after every call, the problem would be right here "modes=SDL_ListModes(NULL, SDL_FULLSCREEN|SDL_HWSURFACE);" since after that no more printf's come out and I get the Segmentation Fault message.

Comment: Maybe look in this: https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=3441&sid=964c840d9a6461f79e00ccd745da6c1c. If it is not your case, double-check your test code (`SDL_Init()` really called? Maybe even try as just `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`, hoping for something interfering)

Comment: Yes, SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) was called already, tried now changing it to SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO), but that didn't make any difference, same results as before.

Comment: Did you explore the situation mentioned on the SDL forum post? Otherwise I am kind of clueless for further assistance, I would have to see the misbehaving system in person to see what can be done. Maybe try some SDL games (first maybe ones from your distro's package manager, for example Heroes may be there) and see how they fall apart or not. If it is systematic, then maybe better visit SDL, and report a bug.

Comment: Reading the forum page a recalled the reason that made me install SDL via the Synaptic Package Manager. It was because when trying to install it via tar.gz file from the official SDL site, I've got the following error "recipe for target 'build/SDL_x11dyn.lo' failed" during the instalation. But with the new instalation I've made (Synaptic) I didn't got any warnings or error messages. Is it possible that it could be some kind of bug or conflict with that X11 system? (downloading the game Heroes now to see if it can lead to any clues)

Comment: Just installed and tried out the game via terminal (the icon is not responsive), got that very same video message:

]0;lazzo@J-Ubuntu: ~lazzo@J-Ubuntu:~$ heroes -J -S
heroes: Falha abrindo visual: No available video device
]0;lazzo@J-Ubuntu: ~lazzo@J-Ubuntu:~$ exit
exit

Comment: @Lazzo: Time for thinking up a bug report (or better, to ask at a more appropriate place first). Probably first try at Ubuntu, search their forums for similar problem (You may also look in Battle for Wesnoth, it is a popular game, and SDL based, so will likely fail on your system), hoping for a solution. If not, try to ask about it. By the way installing from the package repo is usually the way to go as you did at last: Those are supposed to work, you are more likely to find support if something with those break than if using something compiled from source.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem round 1 (compilation):**

The target filename must follow immediately after the -o option, so you should change the order of the arguments:

```
gcc -Wall -o teste teste.c -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

This may not solve all your build problems, but it is a good start.

**Problem round 2 (adding error handling):**

The call to `SDL_SetVideoMode` returned null. If you get a return value of null you should call SDL_GetError immediately after to check what the error is:

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
if (screen == NULL) {
    printf("SDL_SetVideoMode failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1); /* Unrecoverable error */
}
```

You should add similar handling for the other SDL calls.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the syntax following that exact order, but now, when trying to execute the program (./teste) all I get is:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @Lazzo that'd be a separate question (also you should look at using `gdb` or some other debugger)

Comment: Thanks, I've totally edited my question in order for it to match with the new problem I've got. I can't see the need of creating a whole new page since I've still got problems.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that have worked out in my case was to format Ubuntu and try another distro. Right now I am using Linux Mint, and despite that fact that it's totally based on Ubuntu, everything is working as expected now. Just sharing my solution to the problem, in case somebody else have this very same problem someday.